What is the working justification of this circuit?
Made with microcap v12.
This is a circuit on which a question was asked by a user who later deleted the question.

This circuit works at ~ 15 MHz. I would know how I could justify its operation.
How could I do this justification?

So your question is "can't his circuit be simulated"?

Yes. All circuits can be simulated (some could be "calculated" ...) ... if you own the "good" model and if you have the "good" method of doing it ...

Ok, the first information (in the deleted question) was 14 MHz. Until I simulated, did not know. Will change it.

So, the question is "How can I verify that the circuit oscillates at 15 MHz? I'm not real clear about what you're asking that your answer answers.

Probably "error" due to my ignorance of the "English" language ...

For crystal oscillators, TRANsient response is very tedious because high crystal Q means very long simulation runs. The merit of transient simulations is seeing what non-linear transistor effects eventually limit oscillating amplitude.
If you want to determine the point where positive feedback fails to maintain oscillations, AC analysis goes much, much faster.
For example, you may wish to find out what crystal quality factor is required to oscillate...if the crystal's motional resistance (Rm) is too high, you have a failed oscillator.
A LTSPICE AC analysis was performed on the following circuit (similar to OP's). It is excited by a current source - its amplitude doesn't matter because the whole circuit is linearized around the transistor bias point.

The crystal's internal motional resistance was varied between 70 to 75 ohms in one ohm steps. As resistance steps higher, at some point the output phase plot shifts dramatically away from zero (360) degrees. Somewhere between 71 -to- 72 ohms oscillation fails.


Made with microcap v12.
The circuit have a Nyquist plot which can give gain and phase margin.
Here is the picture of this behavior.

A "enlarged" picture shows the "gain" and "phase" margins (red lines).
Only a problem of "number" points.

Enlarged ...

Nyquist picture, now ok with gain and phase margins.

And the transient of this circuit.
Note that the "starting" is a "long" time ...

Here is also the AC analysis.


I don't understand your gain margin result. Shouldn't you take it when the phase is 180deg?

I made a new simulation and it seems that the gain margin is correct ... I add into the answer. The red lines show it.
